# librobot_control.so bad plugin info hash

Tags: ros, openrave

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I installed the openrave_robot_control plugin under ROS Diamondback and I was able to successfully run "rosmake" on the source. Then I loaded the plugin into my OPENRAVE_PLUGINS environment variable:
export OPENRAVE_PLUGINS=$OPENRAVE_PLUGINS:`rospack find openrave`/share/openrave/plugins:`rospack find openrave_robot_control`/lib

The issue comes when I run "openrave --listplugins" and I get the following error:
[plugindatabase.h:832] /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/openrave_planning/openrave_robot_control/lib/librobot_control.so failed to load: openrave (InvalidPlugin): [void OpenRAVEGetPluginAttributes(OpenRAVE::PLUGININFO*, int, const char*):87] bad plugin info hash

Anyone else experience this?

Thanks,
Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12224/librobot_control.so-bad-plugin-info-hash/) by [chriscannon](https://answers.ros.org/users/1494/chriscannon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2011-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out the issue was because I had installed OpenRAVE separately from the ROS stack of OpenRAVE. This occurs because during compilation it looks under /usr/bin/openrave which is *not* linked to the ROS stack OpenRAVE. After uninstalling the separate version of OpenRAVE and re-running rosmake in the openrave_robot_control directory everything worked perfectly.

---

Originally posted by [chriscannon](https://answers.ros.org/users/1494/chriscannon/) with karma: 16 on 2011-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0